# VSE freeze trail effect

Tags: video-sequence-editor, workflow, effects

I am talking about this:

[image]

The only way I see to replicate this effect - is to messing around with spline masks and motion trackers. But are there any quicker approaches, because they (TV guys) did it in live broadcasting less than in 10 minutes (in "best moments" replay after sportsman end his run).